# Parse through a string php and replace substrings

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, in PHP and the string has occurrences of the pattern `%%abc%%(some substring)%%xyz%%`

There are multiple occurrences of such substrings within the master string.
Each of these occurrences need to be replaced with a string from within an array
`array('substring1','substring2','substring3','substring4')` depending upon the response of a `function()` which returns back a integer between 1 to 4.

I am not able to figure out an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a situation that calls for [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
// Assume this already exists
function mapSubstringToInteger($str) {
    return (strlen($str) % 4) + 1;
}

// So you can now write this:
$pattern = '/%%abc%%(.*?)%%xyz%%/';
$replacements = array('r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4');
$callback = function($matches) use ($replacements) {
    return $replacements[mapSubstringToInteger($matches[1])];
};

preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $input);
```

Comment: Note that $pattern is a regex string, so if you change $pattern make sure you escape any regex characters

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), like this:

```
preg_replace_callback( '#%%abc%%(.*?)%%xyz%%#', function( $match) {
    // Do some logic (with $match) to determine what to replace it with
    return 'replacement';
}, $master_string);
```